# Show that the transformation of two random variables have the same distribution

Tags: statistics

Given $X_1$ and $X_2$ are RV with standard normal distributions. They are independent.

We define $U=2X_1X_2$ and V = $X_1^2-X_2^2$. How can it be proved that U and V identically distributed? They are not linear transformations so they are not themselves gaussian.

I tried finding the CDFs of U and V. If they are the same then U and V are identically distributed.

so $F_u(U) = P(U<=u) = P(2X_1X_2<u)$
and $F_v(V) = P(V<=v) = P(X_1^2-X_2^2<v)$

I then realized through algebraic manipulation, that

$X_1^2-X_2^2 = sqrt(2X_1X_2+(X_1^2+X_2^2)$

so $X_1^2-X_2^2$ will always be bigger than $2X_1X_2$

so if $P(X_1^2-X_2^2<v)$ then $P(2X_1X_2<v)$. So they hold the same CDF.

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Do you know the polar-coordinates trick for finding the norming constant $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$?

Comment: Making the polar transformation $X_1=R\cos\Theta, X_2=R\sin\Theta$ does the job.

Comment: "$X_1^2-X_2^2$ will always be bigger than $2X_1X_2$" is not correct, for example when $X_1=X_2\not= 0$ and many other examples

Comment: how will polar coordinates help me?